# Angular JS ng-repeat not showing options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

I am trying to populate data from a database into a web page. However, I can't seem to make this work:

```
<div ng-controller="AnalyzerController">
   <select id="Listbox" ng-model="Listofoptions" style="width: 500px">
      <option ng-repeat="option in options" value="{{option}}"> {{option}} </option>
   </select>
   </td>
</div>
```

Here's the javascript code for the controller

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"
   type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
   var analyzer=angular.module('analyzer',[]);
   analyzer.controller('AnalyzerController',function($scope )
   {
    $scope.options = ["A","B","C","D","E"];

   }

</script>
```

In the select box it is showing `{{options}}` and not the values.

Comment: what is not working? do you not see a list of options?

Comment: Why not use `ng-options`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the closing parenthesis for the controller function, that's why you don't see the value.

AFAIK It's prefered to use ng-options along with ng-model, please see [Choosing between ngRepeat and ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) to know the benefits

```js
var analyzer=angular.module('analyzer',[]);
        
analyzer.controller('AnalyzerController', function($scope)
{
 $scope.options = ["A","B","C","D","E"];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="analyzer">
  <div ng-controller="AnalyzerController">
      <select id="Listbox" ng-model="Listofoptions" style="width: 500px">                  
        <option ng-repeat="option in options" value="{{option}}"> {{option}} </option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @SamWilson Don't forget to mark Abdul's answer as the correct one.